# How to remove a painted object if it meets a certain criteria

Tags: java, paintcomponent

So we are to code a Biljard game i java, which is the main goal of the project. However, the project is divided in to three steps. Firstly we were given a "shell" for the table, and two balls. When you simulated the shall it draws a table without "holes" and the balls does not collide with each others nor does they collide with the walls. The first exercise was to make them collide.

However now we are to continue the build to a "disease game" where friction of the table is zero and are specific number of balls are simulated as healthy or contaminated. To make keep this text short the main problem is to "remove" the balls that have died. So when u run the project 30 balls in random positions and velocities appears. Given some probability some balls are contaminated and will contaminate other balls during a collision at a given probability. Then a timer starts and they can either die or recover. However when they die, the balls should disappear. And i can not make that happen. Now i've made them change color to black.

How do I stop the paint component for a ball that is "killed"? I want them to simply disappear from the table...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the ball to null?

Assuming that you have a class Ball which is instantiated like

```
Ball b = new Ball(someArguments);
```

then you draw the ball b in the paint method.

If you then at some point set

```
b = null;
```

the garbage collector should delete your object and take it out of the memory, and the paint method should stop drawing it.

Cheers,

Lucky

Comment: The thing is the the paint component which draw the balls in in the table class. There I have a forloop that loops from 1 to num_balls which is currently set to 30. I have a killAndRemove method which repaints all the dead balls to black at the moment but instead of black i want to simply remove the balls which have status "dead". So I can not put a single ball to null. Am i right? @Dat Luckey

Comment: I assume each ball has a boolean isAlive. If this bool is set to false, your killAndRemove method could remove it from the array in which it is stored. When the for-loop iterates through that array, it will not paint the ball anymore. Its not that easy to tell since I don't know your code. I once created a videogame (2d shooter), where all enemys where stored inside a ArrayList which was iterated inside the draw() method. When an enemy died, I just had to remove it from this list and it was gone from the screen. However, setting the object to null makes sure it is removed from the RAM...Cheers

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell: In my videogame, each enemy had overwritten the draw method, so when it was removed it could not paint itself, I'm not sure how you managed this. I give you the advise to overwrite the paint() method inside the ball class. In your "MAIN-Paint" method, you then do ball[i].draw(). Hope this can somehow help you.

Comment: Since im new to this im not sure of all the syntax, eventhough i completely understand what you are implying. For now i made an if-condition in the loop which drawing the balls. So now when their status is DEAD, they it stops painting. However you can see the balls that are alive, bump in to the dead ghostballs haha! Anyways, i will try to implement what you are suggesting. Ty! Oh and btw im not using a boolean. simply put, i have a statuses which are a private final string DEAD="DEAD" so on and so forth. So I might have to use something from that to remove them from the ArrayList